# Code Repeats when its not supposed to

Tags: java

```
Welcome to the dungeon!
Type Start to begin
Start
Start
--------------------------------------
# Gang Member has appeared! #

Your HP: 200
Gang Member's HP: 75

What would you like to do?
1. Attack
2. Drink health potion
3. Run
Invalid command
Your HP: 200
Gang Member's HP: 75

What would you like to do?
1. Attack
2. Drink health potion
3. Run
Invalid command
Your HP: 200
Gang Member's HP: 75
```

I'm making a text based adventure game to practice java for my robotics club, and my code keeps repeating after it states the enemy and it repeats whats above in the console. The whole code is under, it may be a simple syntax error but i can't find where or whats wrong with it.

```
package idk;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
/**
*
* @author Jack
 */
public class Idk{

/**
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // System objects
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();


    // Player variables
    int health = 200;
    int attackDmg = 50;
    int numHealthPots = 3;
    int healthPotionHealAmount = 45;
            //String enemy = [rand.nextInt(idk.enemies.enems.length
            boolean running = false;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the dungeon!");
            System.out.println("Type Start to begin");
            String input = in.nextLine();
            if(input.equals("Start") ){
                running = true;
            }



    // Label
            GAME:

    while (running) {                       
                int enemyNumber = rand.nextInt(6);
                int enemyHealth;
                int enemyAttackDamage;
                int healthPotionDropChance;
                String enemy /*= "no enemy"*/;        
            switch(enemyNumber){   
                case 0:
                   enemy = "Alien";
                   enemyHealth =75;
                   enemyAttackDamage = 25;
                   healthPotionDropChance = 35; 
                   break;

                case 1:
                   enemy = "Thief";
                   enemyHealth = 90;
                   enemyAttackDamage = 30;
                   healthPotionDropChance = 45; 
                   break;
                case 2:
                    enemy = "Ravager";
                    enemyHealth = 100;
                    enemyAttackDamage = 36;
                    healthPotionDropChance = 45;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    enemy = "Gang Boss";
                    enemyHealth = 150;
                    enemyAttackDamage = 45;
                    healthPotionDropChance = 45;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    enemy = "Gang Member";
                    enemyHealth = 75;
                    enemyAttackDamage = 55;
                    healthPotionDropChance = 35;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    enemy = "Mercenary";
                    enemyHealth = 250;
                    enemyAttackDamage = 18;
                    healthPotionDropChance = 25;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    enemy = "Gang Boss With His Crew";
                    enemyHealth = 205;
                    enemyAttackDamage = 25;
                    healthPotionDropChance = 65 ;
                    break;
                default:
                    enemy = "no enemy showed up";
                    enemyHealth = 1;
                    enemyAttackDamage = 1;
                    healthPotionDropChance = 1 ;
                    break;
                }
                    input = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");                       
        System.out.println("\t# " + enemy + " has appeared! #\n");

        while (enemyHealth > 0) {
            System.out.println("\tYour HP: " + health);
            System.out.println("\t" + enemy + "'s HP: " + enemyHealth);
            System.out.println("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("\t1. Attack");
            System.out.println("\t2. Drink health potion");
            System.out.println("\t3. Run");
            if (input.equals("1")) {
                int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(attackDmg);
                int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDamage);

                enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                health -= damageTaken;

                System.out.println("\t> You strike the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage");
                System.out.println("\t> You recieved " + damageTaken + " in retaliation");

                if (health < 1) {
                    System.out.println("\t You have taken too much damage, you are too weak to go on");
                    break;
                }
            } else if (input.equals("2")) {

                if (numHealthPots > 0) {
                    health += healthPotionHealAmount;
                    numHealthPots--;
                    System.out.println("\t> You drank a health potion, healed for: " + healthPotionHealAmount + "."
                            + "\n\t> You now have" + health + "HP."
                            + "\n\t> You now have" + numHealthPots + " health potions left.\n");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\t> You have no health potions, defeat enemies for a chance to get one");
                }

            } else if (input.equals("3")) {
                System.out.println("\t> You run away from the " + enemy);
                continue GAME;
            } else {
                System.out.println("\tInvalid command");
            }
        }
        if (health < 1) {
            System.out.println("You limp out of the dungeon, weak from battle.");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(" # " + enemy + " was defeated! # ");
        System.out.println(" # You have " + health + "HP left # ");
        // If the random number is less than 50 it drops
        if (rand.nextInt(100) < healthPotionDropChance) {
            numHealthPots++;
            System.out.println(" # The " + enemy + " dropped a health potion. # ");
            System.out.println(" # You now have " + numHealthPots + " health potion(s). # ");
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("What would you like to do now?");
        System.out.println("1. Continue fighting");
        System.out.println("2. Exit dungeon");

        while (!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("invalid command");
            input = in.nextLine();

        }
        if (input.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("You continue your adventure.");
        } else if (input.equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("You exit the dungeon.");
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("######################");
    System.out.println("# THANKS FOR PLAYING #");
    System.out.println("######################");
}
}
```

Comment: Once you've solved your problem, consider posting it to Code Review. You're trying to do far too much in your `main()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Brother you have forgotten a `input.nextInt()` after asking for the options to the user.